# Effects of light from LED

Tags: solid-state-physics

There are many rumurs that light emitted by LED is very harmful for our eyes. Is it true?
I know that blue light have high freq. so it may harm what about other spectra.

Comment: This depends a great deal on wavelength and power. For wavelengths about 405nm, the laser safety standard IEC60825 is applicable (it is applicable to all light) and prescribes safe power limits. You would need to check any particular device against that standard. Between 405nm and the middle of the visible range, phototoxicity is often the dominant hazard; above 800nm, there is almost no phototoxicity risk and the main risk is whether a device will load the retina with too much power and damage this organ by heating. Below 405nm phototoxicity risk is extreme, even for very low ...

Comment: ... light levels. For example, the UV in sunlight means that those who live / work in marine / snow environments especially before 20 years of age (the lens becomes more opaque to UV after this age) have increased risk of cataracts, retinal lesions and retinal cancer later in life.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by 'LED'.  For instance I use red LEDs (and reasonably high-power ones: they're used for rear lights in cars) as a safelight for B/W printing.  I am very certain that they have utterly negligible output any wavelength shorter than ~600nm (and probably longer than that) since I leave paper exposed to them for many minutes with no fogging.  But a white or blue LED is a different animal.  So 'LED' is not a precise enough term.

Comment: http://www.hexatechinc.com/uv-c-led.html  Definitely harmful!

Answer (score 0):

Technically all light is harmful to the eye as a side effect of entropy, however, you will die of old age before your eye weakens 0.1% by looking at a normal LED. It is a lot more damaging to say, look at the sidewalk on a bright day or to look at the clouds without sunglasses. An easy rule with light is that if you stare at it for five seconds then look away and see black rings, it is not safe.

Comment: What is a "normal LED" these days?  Single emitters rated for multiple tens of Watts are getting to be pretty normal in outdoor lighting fixtures these days.  I don't have numbers for the irradiance, but I'm pretty sure I wouldn't want to stare at one up-close and without a diffuser.